# VBA: Assign hyperlink from cell to object

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

My dashboard is locked so colleagues can't change/delete anything by accident.

I need them to be able to add a hyperlink to a button, however.

I've created a 'Set Up' sheet which allows them to input information which will then be reflected on the dashboard (KPIs, title, etc.). I want this to include a button which will assign a hyperlink from B5 on 'Set Up' to the button on the dashboard (named 'CoverageButton').

Here's the Set Up sheet, using Google as a stand in link:

[image: Set Up Sheet]

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
Sub AssignURL()

Dim fileLink As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveWorkbook

fileLink = Cells(5, 2) 'indicating where link is
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Shapes("CoverageButton"), _
    Address:=fileLink

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'm getting a run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method, highlighting the line starting with `.Hyperlinks`. Using 2016 version of Excel.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Shapes` is a property of a worksheet, not a workbook.

Also, you aren't qualifying Cells correctly.

```vb
Sub AssignURL()
Dim fileLink As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' add link to 'CoverageButton' on 'Dashboard' sheet
    With ActiveSheet
        fileLink = .Cells(5, 2)                  
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Shapes("CoverageButton"), _
        Address:=fileLink
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note, if the button is on a different sheet you would want to use something like this where we explicitly reference the `Set Up` and `Dashboard` sheets.

```vb
Sub AssignURL()
Dim fileLink As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' get link from 'Set Up' sheet
    fileLink = Sheets("Set Up").Cells(5, 2).Value

    With Sheets("Dashboard")
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Shapes("CoverageButton"), _
        Address:=fileLink
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Norie, this is helpful. It's now telling me the item with the specified name wasn't found, seemingly referring to ```"CoverageButton"```. I had defined the name of the button as "CoverageButton" - I'm guessing I'm not calling it up properly - i.e. ```.Shapes``` isn't the right approach?

Comment: If the 'active' sheet has a shape named `CoverageButton` the code should work,  I'll add to my answer to suggest something that might help.

Comment: Ah. The shape named ```CoverageButton``` is on a different sheet ```Dashboard```.

Comment: Your second option referring to the two sheets explicitly makes a lot of sense. For the life of me I can't get it to find ```CoverageButton```. When I defined its name, its scope was Workbook. It is on the sheet ```Dashboard```. In the code you've suggested, it's referring to the correct sheet. There was no spacing in my naming of it, and the spelling all matches up.

Comment: Right. The code works when I use the name ```Rectangle: Rounded Corners 3``` instead of the name I gave it. Thanks for your help Norie.

Comment: Where did you try setting the name of the shape? To name a shape you would select it, enter the new name in the Name Box to the left of the formula bar and hit Return. If the shape you want to refer to is the only one on the sheet you could refer to it by index i.e. Shapes(1) .